# Find vtkImageData origin and size

Tags: c++, vtk

I have an app with 3 viewports (3 vtkRenderers). Over everyone of them I have a vtkImageReslice. These vtkImageReslice can be zoomed, shifted, rotated, etc.

I get a task to draw a line (vtkLine or something) over every vtkImageReslice ... how can I know the origin and size of vtkImageReslice on every vtkRenderer ?

Knowing the origin and size of vtkRenderer is pretty simple:

```
int* pOrigin = m_pRenderer->GetOrigin();
int* pSize = m_pRenderer->GetSize();
TRACE("Origin: %d.%d, Size: %d.%d\n", pOrigin[0], pOrigin[1], pSize[0], pSize[1]);
```

On m_pRenderer I have a m_pReslice (vtkImageReslice) ... how can I know the origin and the size of m_pReslice to draw a line over it ?

I appreciate every hint, advice, anything ...

[Later edit]
I think I am not described well the matter, so I post here a picture:

[image]
the only thing that I have to know is the origin and the size of image data from an specific renderer ... that picture, could be shifted, rotated, zoomed, etc.

[Even later edit]
I attach another picture that illustrate what I am trying to do:

[image]

When I made a zoom to vtiImageActor, the horizontal green line must become wider:

[image]

Comment: The pipeline is: vtkRenderWindow->vtkRenderer->vtkImageActor   and for vtkImageActor: vtkImageReslice->vtkMatrix4x4->vtkLookupTable->vtkImageMapToColors->vtkImageActor ... hope it helps.

Comment: I think that is a matter to transform/find vtkImageData into world coordinates ...

Comment: Is this about to display reference lines or what do you like to achieve?

Comment: I just want to draw a line (vtkAxisActor2D or vtkLine, whatever) over vtkImageActor (which is DICOM image as shows in the above picture). But the issue is that vtkImageActor could be zoomed or shifted, and the line (vtkAxisActor2D or vtkLine) should follow the vtkImageActor ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think about widgets. There a lot of them [VTK Widgets](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK_Widget_Examples)

e.g. the ImagePlaneWidget pipeline

```
vtkImagePlaneWidget myWidget = vtkImagePlaneWidget.New();
myWidget.SetInput(myDicomImageReader.GetOutput());
myWidget.SetPlaneOrientationToYAxes();
myWidget.SetSliceIndex(mySliceIndexNumber);
myWidget.SetInteractor(myInteractor);
myWidget.GetPlaneProperty().SetColor(1.0,0.0,0.0);

vtkOutlineFilter outlineFilter = vtkOutlineFilter.New();
outlineFilter.SetInputConnection(myDicomImageReader.GetOutputPort());

vtkPolyDataMapper mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper.New();
mapper.SetInputConnection(outlineFilter.GetOutputPort();

vtkActor actor = vtkActor.New();
actor.SetMapper(mapper);

myImageViewer.GetRenderer().AddActor(actor);

RenderWindow.Render();
myWidget.On();
```

Comment: I guess that this approach is not an option ... beside that line over image, I need to display another lines on renderer, which must play depend of vtkImageData ... so,in the end, I really need to know the size and the origin of vtkImageData ...

Comment: I just now saw your above code running, and yes, is working great ! Thank you !

Comment: Johnny, the widget from above is working great, but there is possibility to use it as a cross line, not as simple line ?

Answer (score 1):

Well in my degree thesis I did a medical application to slice images and many other things, among were slicing and painting a line on vtk image actor.
I did it in python, I will put a piece of code here, maybe it will helpfull for you. This piece of code does slice and paint a line over this slice, of course, there are many class attributes, but I hope with this code you understand the essence.

```
self.renderXZ = vtk.vtkRenderer()
self.renderXZ.SetBackground(0,0,0)
self.interactorStyleXZ = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleImage()
self.xz.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.renderXZ)
self.xz.SetInteractorStyle(self.interactorStyleXZ)

#creating image actor

    self.imageActorXZ = vtk.vtkImageActor()
    self.imageActorXZ.SetDisplayExtent(self.imageXZ.GetWholeExtent())

#getting the dimensions
    xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, zMin, zMax = self.image.GetWholeExtent()

#changing slice
    self.changeSliceXZ(yMax/2)
    slice = self.imageActorXZ.GetSliceNumber()

    max = self.imageActorXZ.GetWholeZMax()

    self.renderXZ.AddActor(self.imageActorXZ)
    self.xz.GetRenderWindow().SetSize(522,243)
    XZ_XSize,XZ_YSize = self.renderXZ.GetSize()

#drawing a Line
    rectMapper = self.drawLine(0, XZ_YSize/2, XZ_XSize, XZ_YSize/2)
    self.HorizontalLineActorXZ = vtk.vtkActor2D()
    self.HorizontalLineActorXZ.SetMapper(rectMapper)
    self.renderXZ.AddActor2D(self.HorizontalLineActorXZ)

#and the changeSliceXZ function is this

def changeSliceXZ(self,sliceNumber):
    slicer = vtkImageSlicer()
    slicer.SetInput(self.image)

#putting the direction of the slice
    slicer.SetSliceDirection(1)
    slicer.SetSlice(sliceNumber)
    slicer.Update()

    self.imageXZ = slicer.GetOutput()
    self.imageActorXZ.SetInput(self.imageXZ)
    self.xz.GetRenderWindow().Render()
    self.YSlice = sliceNumber
    self.SliceNumber[1] = sliceNumber
```

Comment: Interesting approach ... I have just one question: what kind of object is "self" ? I am working only in C++, I don't know python at all ...

Comment: I know that "self" means "this" in C++, I just wonder what kind of object is ... but I get the idea ... I don't know if using a 3D (or 2D) vtk object coupled onto vtkImageActor could be an option, because I need to setup lines outer of vtkImageActor, but that should act just like vtkImageActor ... Thanks again.